# Where is GCM documentation for 'InvalidTokenVersion' error?

Tags: error-handling, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the Google Cloud Messaging services described at [https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) but I am getting a HTTP response status of 400 and this response text:
`{"error":"InvalidTokenVersion"}`

At the time I write this, that exact error code has zero results on Google! Has anyone else encountered it? I could understand "InvalidToken" but it is the "Version" bit which is confusing me.

I'd like to see a nice list of all the possible error codes for the `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/` and `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/*/rel/topics/*` services, if you know where that is?!

All the GCM pages say at present is...

> HTTP status 400 (Bad request) - request parameters are missing or invalid. Check error messages for detailed information.

---

**Background information:**
I am using a registration token from an Android device which still shows a log of successful notifications in the GCM Diagnostics (part of Google Play Developer Console). So surely the token cannot be wrong?
If I try a token value of "bum" I get error "InvalidToken" instead.
However, trying to send a new notification with `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` results in the "InvalidRegistration" error, so I guess something has gone screwy.
I'd like to claim that I've changed nothing recently, but something to do with SSL on the server might have expired I suppose.

Comment: Hi Magnus Smith. Just wanted to check in if you were able to figure this out? :)

Comment: Nope. And now everything has been superseded by FCM anyway!

Comment: Thanks for replying back. :D I see. I managed to see another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42418935/4625829) where the same response is shown. I have a feeling that this might be related to the format of the token. When you posted this, were you using a token with a colon (`:`) (*new format*)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot remember about a colon. Since this was an Android token, I'm sure I was just grabbing whatever token the client app was given by GCM.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much anyways. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

The token you are providing is regId not instanceId.token. Follow the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client.

see examples here.

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart