# Firebase Topic Message Received Status using Google API

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently, I integrated the Firebase Topic concept in my APP and near to 2K users was subscribed and I', triggering notifications daily via my app server.

What I want to know is how many users are getting delivered and failed. Because if some users are not getting delivered and failed, I'll set a retry of the notification  to those members again. Any ideas about this?

I also tried the following URL via ARC (Advanced Rest Client) for getting the information about all my topics in my current project with following API:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/APA91bHQ3Jp2NPrVF7z_1a8qNgg_YGI-
zPhnxnpumCeckvieHACuwaIWPlaR....QcChUOhk4T62vAc_0PC8HVk4p4D?details=true

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=<SERVER_KEY>
```

SERVER_KEY -> ( Firebase Console -> Settings -> Cloude message -> Legacy Server key )

But I am getting the response status:

```
400: Bad Request
{
"error": "InvalidTokenVersion"
}
```

Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tested it out on my end. I also received the same `InvalidTokenVersion` when I used a token that started with `APA`. When I tested a token with a colon (`:`), it returned as expected. So now I'm fairly sure this has something to do with the registration token.

Comment: colon (:) means like this right?...https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/APA91b....:details=true

Comment: Nope. It has to be a part of the registration token. For example, my token in the old format is like this `APA91bG....sLI`. A token with a new format (with colon `:`) is like this `cEV....V4:APA91...l0k1GWMuA`. See the colon between the two strings?

Comment: Refer this url : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0g5_07sb2TxNVhla0NUbFRuNnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The colon is a part of the registration token. Not the request. Did you *re-generate* a token from the device?

Comment: I re-generated the device token again, its comes again start with "APA" without colon only...

Comment: Glad to see you made it work. Was the registration token format the cause of it, like I suspected it to be?

Comment: Problem is I creating the registration token using multiple senderid..like FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderids, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE).... If i am using like this, then i will get and start with Token id "APA".... Otherwise i am getting what you said like ":"... Now prefectly working... One more clarification.. how will create the registration token for multiple senderid

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no available API that you can use in order to trace if a message has been received by the device when using Topics Messaging.

You'll have to implement your own way to somehow *acknowledge* that the message from the topic has been received by your client app, if it didn't receive it, then have your App Server do a retry.

On a side note, when using FCM, it is highly advised to make use of the Server Key instead of the *Legacy* Server Key.

---

With regards to the `InvalidTokenVersion` response. It seems that it is related to the registration token. I tried it out on my end and was able to replicate the response, but only when using a registration token with the old format (starts with `APA` with no colon "`:`").

But when I tested a token with the new format, it returned expected response. I'm fairly sure this has something to do with the registration token somehow.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Server Key, still i am getting the same error : "InvalidTokenVersion".

Comment: I refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key and used Current_Key from Google-Services.json and used and tried. I am getting error "401 Unauthorized"...

Comment: I see that the token you have has the old format (starts with `APA`). Could you try to generate a new token where it should show one that uses the new format (one with a colon `:`).

Comment: Also, you should just use the Server Key. 401 is caused by using an invalid Server API Key. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).

Comment: Were you able to try in generating a new registration token?

Comment: I tried the same process and generate new registration id for new devices and use the same url via ARC ( Advance Rest Client ) but the same error i am getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136553/discussion-between-user2488539-and-al).

Comment: Perfectly working after creating the New Register Token... Previously i am creating Token by using SenderId. So i am getting old one. like FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderids, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE)

Comment: @user2488539 Previously you were creating Token by using SenderId and now?