# InvalidTokenVersion for Firebase FCM Android token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging in an Android app. App collects the FCM token and sends it to a remote server where tokens are stored in order to (eventually) send push notifications to users using FCM endpoint

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

App gets the token in this way:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I noticed tokens come in two different formats.

The first format is a 152 characters string starting with xxxxxxxxxxx:APA91b

The second one is 140 characters string starting with APA91b

As far as I understood from this question [Firebase Topic Message Received Status using Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418935/firebase-topic-message-received-status-using-google-api)
the first format is ‘new’ and the second one is ‘old’. But so far I couldn't find any correlation between token format and app version (and Firebase SDK Version) or  Android API level.

The problem is that I can’t send a notification to the client with old format push token.

If I try to get token details using Instance ID endpoint https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info I receive “InvalidTokenVersion” error.

What I would like to know is:

- why do clients with the same app version generate different token format?
- is there a way to use old format tokens or convert them to the new one?

Thanks

Comment: Did the app previously use GCM?  You can force regeneration of the token by resetting the instance ID: [FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId).  A brute force fix would be to deploy a version of the app that tests for the 140 char token and resets IID if found.

Comment: @BobSnyder no it didn't. Anyway forcing regeneration could be a way, although I'll get new tokens only from clients that will open the app after the update.

Comment: You can configure a `BroadcastReceiver` to run when the app is updated using [Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED). I think you could use that to trigger the IID/token regeneration.  Odd that you are seeing the 140-char tokens if the app has never used GCM or another service (such as Parse) that was based on GCM.

Comment: @BobSnyder interesting, I didn't know that Intent. I'll give it a try. I will also double check for a previous GCM implementation, maybe I missed something. Thank you.

Comment: Agreeing with @BobSnyder The token that starts without the InstanceID prefix (`<IID>:<token>`) is odd. If this behavior continues, I would suggest reaching out to Firebase support directly. Cheers!